# wxPython Menu Open Location

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I'm going through this tutorial here http://zetcode.com/wxpython/menustoolbars/ under the section **Submenus and Separators**. I get the menu items and submenu to display, but my menu opens "to the left" like so:
[image: my menu]

instead of "to the right" like the reference image and all other menu examples I've seen which open like so:
[image: reference menu]

Why is my menu opening the way it is? The window/frame size doesn't seem to matter as far as I can tell. I know the tutorial is Linux based while mine is Windows based, but other Windows based examples also show like the tutorial. Any ideas?

For reference, I'm using VS Code for editing (not that I think that matters), and a standard system install of Python 3.7 and wxPython 4.0.3.

Comment: Menus will normally open to the right unless there is no room, in which case they open to the left. On Windows this can be overridden as a system setting, held in the registry `MenuDropAlignment` although in that case, I suspect that all of your menus would act in the same way. Still I suspect that it something to do with your environment rather than wxpython.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions. I don't think I changed anything, but maybe I'll try setting up the environment elsewhere in the same way and see what the same code does. I'm open to ideas on how to find the right environment change.

Comment: In Windows 10:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/68038-set-menus-open-aligned-left-right-windows-10-a.html